# how to assign each data from array to variable and use each in condition using php?

Tags: php, arrays

i dont how to do it... 
Can anyone help and guide with this..

I have array like this;

```
$record_name = array("john", "dan", "kev", "kyle");
```

now i want to display from .csv file the record which name is on the array..

I want each value in array to put in a condition..

this is my script but it shows nothing...

```
$file  = fopen('sample.csv', 'r');
echo "<table>";
foreach($record_name as $key => $value){

    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
        list($name, $age, $location) = $line;
        if((strpos($name, $value) !==FALSE)){

             echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
            echo "<td>$age</td>";
            echo "<td>$location</td>";
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }

    } 
}   
echo "</table>";
```

please refer with the code..

Comment: What does that mean it shows nothing?

Comment: @bub - yup......the row name in csv file contains the fullname... so i need to use strpos to find the name